# GAE cron every day between interval

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to setup a gae cron task to run on certain days of the week as shown below for at least 10 mins

Ideally the cron job should start at 10:30, then 10:35, 10:40, 10:45 then stop until next day/week

```
  <cron>
    <url>/notificationService</url>
    <description>Weekly cron</description>
    <schedule>every tuesday,wednesday,friday,saturday between 22:30 to 22:45</schedule>   
    <timezone>Africa/Johannesburg</timezone>
  </cron>
```

Please assist, thanks

Babajide

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Cron Schedule Format is either:

- every N (hours|mins|minutes) ["from" (time) "to" (time)]
- ("every"|ordinal) (days) ["of" (monthspec)] (time)

So once you specify the days, you can only specify the absolute time. I think a workaround could be that you specify the time in the cron expression as:

- every 5 minutes from 22:30 to 22:45

and then check if it is a tuesday, wednesday, friday or saturday. Also keep in mind that your job will get fired every 5 minutes irrespective of whether the previous instance completed or not. So if your job is expected to take more than that time to execute, you need to be careful about what you are doing in the job to prevent side effects.

Comment: Thanks, @Romin, I thought of that too but will be too expensive running every N time, I just repeated the cron entry with different time. That should work out but thanks, will accept ur answer.